# EXTJS 4.2 throws 404 Error

Tags: javascript, extjs

By embedding EXTJS 4.2 via

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="File/To/ext-all.js"></script>
```

In Browsers Console (Chrome in my case) throws some 404 errors for some default fields / elements like:

```
http://HostOfMyApp.com/ext/src/data/ModelManager.js?_dc=1487838517748
404 (not found)
```

the same for:

```
../src/field/Hidden.js?_dc=1487838517748
../src/field/Text.js?_dc=1487838517748
../src/layout/Fit.js?_dc=1487838517748
../src/layout/Hbox.js?_dc=1487838517748
../src/layout/VBox.js?_dc=1487838517748
..
```

The files in the above mentionend Example aren´t located on the server, in that path, but i think they hasn´t to be, because EXT loads it from the File itself. Isn´t it ?

The Ext App though starts and loads the Elements like Text Field and works fine.

Any idea to solve the 404 Errors ?

Comment: None of those files exist (or at least, not in those directories), where are they being required?

Comment: Thanks Evan. Thats it.
In one Script there where Required via
'Ext.data.ModelManager',
And that seems to be not necessary :-)